# spring boot integration testing mock method returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I wrote simple spring boot application with `Controller`, `Service` and `Business` classes, but while writing integration test the mock method of `Service` is returning null

**MockMainController**

```
@RestController
public class MockMainController {

@Autowired
private MockBusiness mockBusiness;

@GetMapping("request")
public MockOutput mockRequest() {
    return mockBusiness.businessLogic(new MockInput());

      }

  }
```

**MockBusiness**

```
@Service
public class MockBusiness {

@Autowired
private MockService mockService;

public MockOutput businessLogic(MockInput input) {
    return mockService.serviceLogic(input);
    }
}
```

**MockService**

```
@Service
public class MockService {

@Autowired
private MockUtil mockUtil;

public MockOutput serviceLogic(MockInput input) {

    mockUtil.exchange(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(" "), HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<MockOutput>() {
            });
    return new MockOutput();

     }

 }
```

I'm trying to mock the `MockService` bean in application context using `@MockBean`

**MockControllerTest**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Profile("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MockControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMainController mockMainController;

@MockBean
private MockService mockService;

@Test
public void controllerTest() {
    MockOutput output = mockMainController.mockRequest();
    given(this.mockService.serviceLogic(ArgumentMatchers.any(MockInput.class)))
            .willReturn(new MockOutput("hello", "success"));
    System.out.println(output);    //null
     }

 }
```

In the test method I created mock service bean using `@MockBean` I'm not having any error here but `System.out.println(output);` prints `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `null` because of wrong statements order in your test method. You first call controller method and you get what's inside default `@MockBean` which is in this case `null`. Swap statement:

```
MockOutput output = mockMainController.mockRequest();
```

with

```
given(this.mockService.serviceLogic(ArgumentMatchers.any(MockInput.class)))
        .willReturn(new MockOutput("hello", "success"));
```

and you will get expected result.